# Super large matrix generation from MySQL tables?

Tags: matrix, cluster-analysis

I have two MySQL tables with one containing a set of 6000 users and another set of 10000 ratings they have provided for products. I'd like to make a matrix of feature vectors that have for each row that denotes a user a 1 or 0 if they have given a rating to a particular product (or even the rating value). What is the best way to accomplish this (given too that the matrix will be sparse?).

I'm curious as to what implementations I can test out with tools at my disposal (like MySQL or MATLAB) - the end purpose is to perform clustering of similar users. Somehow I think a 10,000 column MySQL table won't make my db admin happy... at all.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way of storing a *sparse* matrix in SQL is to use three columns, where `user` and `product` together are the primary key, and the extra column is the rating.

It does not make sense to do the actual processing with the SQL database. This is just a huge overhead, and makes things slow. Just get the data out into a primitive and fast data structure, do the analysis, then eventually translate the output in whatever output format you need.

SQL is good when you need only part of the data or have to perform changes, need locking and all this. But I'd never run the computation directly on the database, because unless you can load your low-level linear algebra libraries into your database, it will be slow.